# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_federated.python.learning' has no attribute 'ModelWeights'

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I use TFF 0.12.0, in this line :

```
model = tff.learning.ModelWeights.from_model('model.h5')
```

I find this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_federated.python.learning' has no attribute 'ModelWeights'
```

How can I change this line to be functional with version 0.12.0
Thanks